# How to load a global module in a project?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I installed lodash in global path. Now in a project js file, I use '_' express the lodash object.

I wrote this in webpack.config.js

`plugins: [new webpack.ProvidePlugin({  _: ['lodash'] })]`

But I got this when npm run build:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash' in 'D:\other\project\src'`

Comment: you should add also the webpack version, it may help with writing the correct solution to your problem, anyway you should take a look at externals from webpack:  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/ it's a property that allows you to provide global libraries into your webpack ecosystem (and there's a specific lodash example in the documentation)

Comment: THANKS! webpack 4.35.0